# Is there a helper to know whether a property has been loaded by Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, lazy-loading, helper

I need a helper to know whether a property has been loaded as a way to avoid `LazyInitializationException`. Is it possible?

```
@Entity
public class Parent {
    @OneToMany
    private List<Child> childList;
}

@Entity
public class Child {

}

"select distinct p from Parent p left join fetch p.childList";

// Answer goes here
// I want to avoid LazyInitializationException
SomeHelper.isLoaded(p.getChildList());
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are two methods, actually.

To find out whether a lazy **property** has been initialized you can invoke [`Hibernate.isPropertyInitialized()`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/api/org/hibernate/Hibernate.html#isPropertyInitialized(java.lang.Object,+java.lang.String)) method with your entity instance and property name as parameters.

To find out whether a lazy **collection** (or entity) has been initialized (like in your example) you can invoke [`Hibernate.isInitialized()`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/api/org/hibernate/Hibernate.html#isInitialized(java.lang.Object)) with collection (entity) instance as parameter.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#pc-contains) for Hibernate 5.4

Hibernate API

```
boolean personInitialized = Hibernate.isInitialized(person);

boolean personBooksInitialized = Hibernate.isInitialized(person.getBooks());

boolean personNameInitialized = Hibernate.isPropertyInitialized(person, "name");
```

JPA

> In JPA there is an alternative means to check laziness using the
>   following javax.persistence.PersistenceUtil pattern (which is
>   recommended wherever possible).

```
PersistenceUtil persistenceUnitUtil = Persistence.getPersistenceUtil();

boolean personInitialized = persistenceUnitUtil.isLoaded(person);

boolean personBooksInitialized = persistenceUnitUtil.isLoaded(person.getBooks());

boolean personNameInitialized = persistenceUnitUtil.isLoaded(person, "name");
```

Comment: Interesting enough, `hibernate.isPropertyInitialized` didn't do the job. Only `persistenceUnitUtil.isLoaded` worked for me. As I am uing JPA over hibernate.