# Why Hibernate.isPropertyInitialized returns true?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a Person class which has a lazy inited collection named autos. After fetch person from database I invoked two hibernate methods named isInitialized(autos) and isPropertyInitialized(personObject,autos) the first shows false, the  second one shows true. why?

```
@Entity
public class Person {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="person",fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Auto> autos;

}


@Entity
public class Auto {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "person_id", nullable = false)
    private Person person;

}
```

**The test code:**

```
Person p = personRepository.findAll().get(0);     
System.out.println(Hibernate.isInitialized(p.getAutos()));
System.out.println(Hibernate.isPropertyInitialized(p,"autos"));
```

**console:**

```
false
true
```

Comment: mat be some information https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1589144/is-there-a-helper-to-know-whether-a-property-has-been-loaded-by-hibernate

Comment: thanks. Already tried it with a field as non collection:
@OneToOne(mappedBy="person",fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private Auto autos;
Still returns true, the first one returns false

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe in this case usage of `Hibernate.isPropertyInitialized` could be not correct.

According to the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#pc-contains) `Hibernate.isPropertyInitialized` should be used to verify laziness for attributes or state e.g. `"name"` for `Person` object. To verify laziness of subentities `Hibernate.isInitialized` should be used

```
boolean personInitialized = Hibernate.isInitialized(person);

boolean personBooksInitialized = Hibernate.isInitialized(person.getBooks());

boolean personNameInitialized = Hibernate.isPropertyInitialized(person, "name");
```

Or preferably as it's mentioned in the documentation  `javax.persistence.PersistenceUtil.isLoaded`

```
PersistenceUtil persistenceUnitUtil = Persistence.getPersistenceUtil();

boolean personInitialized = persistenceUnitUtil.isLoaded(person);

boolean personBooksInitialized = persistenceUnitUtil.isLoaded(person.getBooks());

boolean personNameInitialized = persistenceUnitUtil.isLoaded(person, "name");
```

Now why there is `Hibernate.isPropertyInitialized` and why it's returning always `true`
I believe the main reason is the [Bytecode enhancement](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#BytecodeEnhancement)  and lazy attribute loading.

Typically when fetching an entity all attributes are loaded e.g. `"name"`, `"age"` etc.

> When fetching an entity, all attributes are going to be loaded as
>   well. This is because every entity attribute is implicitly marked with
>   the @Basic annotation whose default fetch policy is FetchType.EAGER. [source](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-lazy-load-entity-attributes-using-jpa-and-hibernate/)

However, with the Bytecode enhancement, we can define which of the attributes should be lazy. This useful when we have some large attributes like blob image. I believe for this particular scenario we need `Hibernate.isPropertyInitialized`

Why in your case it's always returning `true`. If we take a look at the Java Doc of the method we could see that it expects

```
@param proxy The potential proxy
```

If it's `HibernateProxy` then it will be checked if it's uninitialized. If yes you will receive `false` since for proxy laziness all attributes are eagerly initialized, thus proxy is uninitialized then attributes are as well. On the other hand, we have a statement

```
 @return true if the named property of the object is not listed as uninitialized; false otherwise
```

So in your case, you are not using the lazy attribute fetching mechanism and not passing the proxy object since `Person` is already initialized. There is no way to check if the property is listed as uninitialized, therefore `true` is returned.

Comment: If you are using compile-time enhancement, `person.getBooks()` will throw exception. Is there any other way to check if it is initialized?